# can't add categories to a category dtype in pandas

Tags: pandas, categories

I have a pandas dataframe with a field called "promo_type" which I converted to categorical by using astype:

```
df['promo_type'] = df['promo_type'].astype('category')
```

Later on in the code I want to add another category to the field, as follows:

```
df['promo_type'].add_categories('0')
```

And I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'add_categories'
```

I have checked that my pandas version does have add_categories, and that add_categories is an available method for df['promo_type'].

I have no idea why this isn't working.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Maybe `df['promo_type'].cat.add_categories('0')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `cat` accessor. You have to use [`Series.cat.add_categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html):

```
df['promo_type'] = df['promo_type'].cat.add_categories('0')
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'promo_type': ['a', 'b', 'c']}).astype('category')
print(df['promo_type'])

# Output
0    a
1    b
2    c
Name: promo_type, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Add category:

```
df['promo_type'] = df['promo_type'].cat.add_categories('0')
print(df['promo_type'])

# Output
0    a
1    b
2    c
Name: promo_type, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): ['a', 'b', 'c', '0']  # <- HERE
```

**Update**

You can use `add_categories` without `cat` accessor only if you use a `CategoricalIndex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'promo_type': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
catx = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['promo_type'])
print(catx)

# Output
CategoricalIndex(['a', 'b', 'c'], categories=['a', 'b', 'c'], ordered=False, dtype='category', name='promo_type')
```

Modify category:

```
catx = catx.add_categories('0')
print(catx)

# Output
CategoricalIndex(['a', 'b', 'c'], categories=['a', 'b', 'c', '0'], ordered=False, dtype='category', name='promo_type')
```